# Issue with questions asked this year in Tags page

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tags

In the [Tags page](https://stackapps.com/tags) of Stack Apps on each tag, I can see the numbers times it was asked in the recent period. The detail having an issue.

Since it is the first month of the year, so the month's count should be same as the year's count. But both are having different count.

After checking few tags, those year counts are on 2015. For example `api-v2` it shows **9 asked this year**, those are [asked on 2015](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/api-v2?sort=newest&pageSize=10).

I can understand if there is no question is asked on the tag in this month, it will show empty placeholder. If the year count is showing on that purpose, it should **9 asked last year** right.

Screen shot for reference:

[image: Question asked this year issue]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Tags page counts the "year" as the "past 365 days" - not the current calendar year.

[image]

Similarly, the month count is for the past 30 days, and the day count is for the past 24 hours. You can find these out by hovering over the "7 asked this month" or "116 this year" parts of the text to get a tooltip.